# Infinispan query without reflection

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, infinispan

I am investigating Infinispan to speed up my application. An out-of-box configuration works even slower than persisting into SQL Server. I am aware of Hibernate Search config to tune Lucene indexing performance, but I want to start from removing reflection. I know that Hibernate search uses it to convert objects into documents for indexing. The problem is that I can't find a way how can I avoid that.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? Why do you think reflection is the bottle neck? Did you do some profiling? There is no way to avoid reflection. At some stage the entity needs to mapped from object to index "world". Even when using Hibernate ORM only you cannot avoid reflection.

Comment: Reflection is not a performance problem anymore, at least the methods used by Hibernate and Hibernate Search are nowadays very efficient. If you find your bottleneck however, suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: I don't expect reflection to be as fast as direct method call. I am looking for a way to provide my own object-to-document mapping based on direct getter calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a @ClassBridge to define your own mapping; your custom ClassBridge implementation will be handed object instances and you can build the Lucene Document directly from it by access direct fields or invoking getters.

Full examples available here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4102

Still, I am pretty confident that Reflection isn't your performance problem. There is likely something wrong in the configuration or the way you're measuring, I'd suggest to use a profiler to narrow down the problematic area.